# Is Less a single pass compilation process?

Tags: css, less

Does Less perform one pass over the files or does it do multiple passes?

Mainly, I'm concerned if I include another file that redefines variables/mixins, will the variables/mixins be the original or the override values be used for the generation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mixins variables that are declared later in the code override previous code, just like in css if you declare the same class in two places the later ones property values will be the ones to be in effect.